# Splitting out multiple counts with left joins for Report use DLookup

Tags: ms-access, left-join

The code below includes two left joins tied to foreign keys in an archived table. I am trying to create a report where I can have 'FilledBy' split out as separate columns like this image. 'FilledBy' has categories Docline, OCLC, and In House, and the report groups the Journal Titles by each Department.

[image]

The query that pulls data for the table uses the following code. FilledBy is one of the ways the data is grouped by. If I use Access' grouped by report feature to break it down into the FilledBy categories  I can't keep everything on one line. (If there is a way, please let me know!) It wants to place the categories as another column, which is space inefficient for this report.

```
SELECT Count(ArchiveTable.ArchiveID) AS TotalRQ, ArchiveTable.ISSN, _
       PatronDatabase.Department, JournalTable.JournalTitle, ArchiveTable.FilledBy
FROM (ArchiveTable _
LEFT JOIN PatronDatabase ON ArchiveTable.PatronID = PatronDatabase.PatronID) _ 
LEFT JOIN JournalTable ON ArchiveTable.ISSN = JournalTable.ISSN
WHERE (((DatePart("yyyy",[RequestDate]))=2016) AND ((PatronDatabase.PatronType)="Staff") _ 
AND ((ArchiveTable.FolderStatus)="Filled"))
GROUP BY ArchiveTable.ISSN, PatronDatabase.Department, JournalTable.JournalTitle, _
         ArchiveTable.FilledBy;
```

Is there a way to have the subtotals fill in? I tried a DLookup in unbound fields in the report. All it gave me were a bunch of 1's.

```
= DLookup("[TotalRQ]", "QryJournalRQbyDept", "ISSN = " & Reports![NRpt]![ISSN] _ 
AND "Department = " & Reports![NRpt]![Department] _ 
AND "FilledBy = OCLC")
```

Comment: What does "'FilledBy' has categories Docline, OCLC, and In House" mean? FilledBy seems to be a column of ArchiveTable. Do you mean, that FilledBy can have the values  "Docline", "OCLC" or "In House"?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Values can have those three results, Docline, OCLC, or In house

Comment: maybe use an `iif(FilledBy='Docline',1,0)` type syntax, then sum that field in the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I created three new queries (one for each category, Docline, OCLC, In House) that calculated the subtotals grouped by Department and ISSN.

Then I created a fourth query using this code to string the results together. I've substituted the actual query names with 'a','b','c' to clarify:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ISSN, a.JournalTitle, a.Department, 
  (SELECT SUM(DoclineRQ) FROM b WHERE a.ISSN = b.ISSN _ 
      AND a.Department = b.Department) AS DoclineTotal, _ 
  (SELECT SUM(OCLCRQ) FROM c WHERE a.ISSN = c.ISSN _ 
      AND a.Department = c.Department) AS OCLCTotal, _ 
  (SELECT SUM(InHouseRQ) FROM d WHERE a.ISSN = d.ISSN _ 
      AND a.Department = d.Department) AS DocDelTotal, _ 
  Nz([DoclineTotal])+Nz([OCLCTotal])+Nz([InHouseTotal]) AS TotalRQ
  FROM a;
```

Now I can tie the report to the final query and it will work.

Credit to Boyd P who answered a similar question I had 9 months ago for the overall structure of the code. I realized I could add additional criteria (the AND statement) and I changed it to SUM and it worked.